# Parse URL as a Command

Tags: zsh

When I enter a git repo url in terminal it has the following output:

```
% https://github.com/chmln/sd.git        
zsh: no such file or directory: https://github.com/chmln/sd.git
```

I want `https://github.com/chmln/sd.git` to act as a command which will

```
git clone https://github.com/chmln/sd.git
cd sd
```

I tried `preexec` hook.

```
preexec () { 
    print ">>>preexec start<<<"
    # print -l ${(qqq)@}

    if  [[ ${(qqq)@} =~ ^https.* ]]
    then
    echo URL
    fi
    print ">>>preexec end<<<"

}
```

The output is

```
% https://github.com/chmln/sd.git
>>>preexec start<<<
>>>preexec end<<<
zsh: no such file or directory: https://github.com/chmln/sd.git
```

How can I address this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function _accept-line-with-url {

    if  [[ $BUFFER =~ ^https.*git ]]
    then

        echo $BUFFER >> $HISTFILE
        fc -R

        BUFFERz="git clone $BUFFER && cd $(basename $BUFFER .git)"
        zle .kill-whole-line
        BUFFER=$BUFFERz
        zle .accept-line
    else 
        zle .accept-line
    fi 
}

zle -N accept-line _accept-line-with-url
```

Now you can paste the github url in the prompt and it will clone the repo.